# Child element not implemented in browser ( CSS)

Tags: html, css

When I inspect elements in the browser one of CSS's child elements is not appearing (bottom-cloud) but the other element appears (top-cloud) and the changes are not being reflected:

```css
.top-container {
  background-color: #E8F9FD;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.middle-container .bottom-container .top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <h1> Hi</h1>
  <p>tester</p>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud2.png" alt="cloud-img">

  <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> one of CSS's child elements is not appearing (bottom-cloud)

`bottom-cloud` does not appear because of `position: absolute` with the bottom-left position. If you want to see it you can try to remove `position: absolute` or modify the bottom-left position like below

```css
.top-container {
  background-color: #E8F9FD;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.middle-container .bottom-container .top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <h1> Hi</h1>
  <p>tester</p>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud2.png" alt="cloud-img">

  <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
```

---

> the other element appears (top-cloud) and the changes are not being reflected

Your selector `.middle-container .bottom-container .top-cloud` does not align with element structure.

According to your selector, your element structure should be

```
<div class="middle-container">
   <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="top-cloud"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For example, I've changed your selector to `.top-container .top-cloud`

```css
.top-container {
  background-color: #E8F9FD;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.top-container .top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <h1> Hi</h1>
  <p>tester</p>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud2.png" alt="cloud-img">

  <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
```